# Highlighting syntax errors in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

In Sublime text 2 when I make an error like forget a `;` or add an extra closing or opening tag there is no highlighting that tells me that I have made a mistake. Only after running the code will I know that a mistake was made. Is this normal for Sublime Text 2 or is it just me? If this is normal, is there any extension to fix this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I use [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2) which highlights potential errors in a number of languages when you save a file.

Comment: for this to work,you first have to install SL,then php library on your system(written in the docs).. is there any simple package that marks error on the go,without having to do to much.something like php storm..

Answer (score 2):

use one of this http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/09/29/3-essential-sublime-text-plugins-for-node-and-javascript-developers/

I prefer jshint, hope to help!